# How can I modify a list of objects which is already filled and appears in a combo box?

Tags: c#

I want to take select the item from the combo box and the by typing new Name(for example) in the text box 
to update it in the list which is in the combo box?

Comment: Your question as it stands is very vague. It's not clear what you are asking. Also, you don't give any clue as to what technology you're using. We have comboboxes in ASP.NET, both pre-Core and Core, as well as WPF and WinForms. Finally, you should show what you've tried, and explain why it doesn't do what you want. Hopefully we'll be able to help you then

Comment: This question is extremely low quality, unanswerable and will be closed unless you can put more effort in. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows Forms you can do something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBox.Items.Add("Test1");
            comboBox.Items.Add("Test2");
            comboBox.Items.Add("Test3");
        }

        private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox.SelectedIndex >= 0)
                comboBox.Items[comboBox.SelectedIndex] = (sender as TextBox).Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that initializing the Combobox in the Constructor is just for demonstration purpose and is not recommended.